# Is it possible to save and retrieve a Gesture using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android-gesture

/res/raw doesn't appear to be an option and saving to SD is fine but i'd prefer to avoid that dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating this SharedPrefs appears to be impossible and a bad idea.  GestureLibrary.fromPrivateFile() does the job saving the file privately off SD.